# What Vim command to use to delete all text after a certain character on every line of a file?

Tags: regex, vim, vi, replace

Scenario:

- I have a text file that has pipe (as in the `|` character) delimited data.
- Each field of data in the pipe delimited fields can be of variable length, so counting characters won't work (or using some sort of substring function... if that even exists in Vim).

Is it possible, using Vim to delete all data from the second pipe to the end of the line for the entire file? There are approx 150,000 lines, so doing this manually would only be appealing to a masochist...

For example, change the following lines from:

```
1111|random sized text 12345|more random data la la la|1111|abcde
2222|random sized text abcdefghijk|la la la la|2222|defgh
3333|random sized text|more random data|33333|ijklmnop
```

to:

```
1111|random sized text 12345
2222|random sized text abcdefghijk
3333|random sized text
```

I'm sure this can be done somehow... I hope.

**UPDATE:** I should have mentioned that I'm running this on Windows XP, so I don't have access to some of the mentioned *nix commands (`cut` is not recognized on Windows).

Comment: Install the *nix commands dude. You'll never regret it. I use cygwin on XP, but I think that these days there are more open alternatives.

Comment: I've considered doing that. I just have to be careful installing not standard stuff on my PC at work. Luckily as a developer they do give us more leeway than a standard user.

Comment: See also a similar (more recent) question "[How to delete text after a specified symbol in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459677/how-to-delete-text-after-a-specified-symbol-in-vim/7460037#7460037)".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
:%s/^\v([^|]+\|[^|]+)\|.*$/\1/
```

Comment: Turns on "very magic" mode for that regex.  It lets you avoid backslash-escaping parens and pluses and whatnot.  See :h /\v

Answer (score 18):

You can also record a macro:

```
qq02f|Djq
```

and then you will be able to play it with `100@q` to run the macro on the next 100 lines.

Macro explanation:

- `qq`: starts macro recording;
- `0`: goes to the first character of the line;
- `2f|`: finds the second occurrence of the `|` character on the line;
- `D`: deletes the text after the current position to the end of the line;
- `j`: goes to the next line;
- `q`: ends macro recording.

Comment: This will stop working prematurely if any line doesn't have two | on it, but works otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have to use Vim, another alternative would be the unix `cut` command:

```
cut -d '|' -f 1-2 file > out.file
```

Answer (score 4):

Just another Vim way to do the same thing:

```
%s/^\(.\{-}|\)\{2}\zs.*//
%s/^\(.\{-}\zs|\)\{2}.*//  " If you want to remove the second pipe as well.
```

This time, the regex matches as few characters as possible (`\{-}`) that are followed by `|`, and twice (`\{2}`), they are ignored to replace all following text (`\zs`) by nothing (`//`).

Comment: Same here. Nice that this answer actually explains what it is doing a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of substitution, one can use the `:normal` command to repeat
a sequence of two Normal mode commands on each line: `2f|`, jumping
to the second `|` character on the line, and then `D`, deleting
everything up to the end of line.

```
:%norm!2f|D
```

Comment: Or even `:%no<S-Tab>2f|D`. Your answer is the best by far in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:command` to make a user command to run the substitution:

```
:command -range=% YourNameHere <line1>,<line2>s/^\v([^|]+\|[^|]+)\|.*$/\1/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
:%s/^\([^\|]\+|[^\|]\+\)\|.*$/\1/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Awk:

```
awk -F"|" '{$0=$1"|"$2}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that vim isn't great at handling very large files. I'm not sure how large your file is. Maybe cat and sed together would work better.

Comment: Anyway, 150000 lines of that type should be OK with Vim.

Comment: I've had 100MB+ files (generated) and Vim is the only editor I've seen that will handle them... I don't know why you would be having problems with it!

Comment: WOrked fine with this file =)

Comment: And I had edited 20 Gb logfiles with vim regexes. Yeah it was slow. But did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed solution:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^|]*|[^|]*\).*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use Vim? Why not just run

```
cat my_pipe_file | cut -d'|' -f1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will filter all lines in the buffer (`1,$`) through cut to do the job:

```
:1,$!cut -d '|' -f 1-2
```

To do it only on the current line, try:

```
:.!cut -d '|' -f 1-2
```