# How to delete text after a specified symbol until the end of the line in Vim?

Tags: vim

My data is of the form:

```
id|name|things that I don't care
```

So for each line I want to delete text after the second `|` symbol.

How do I do this in Vim with one command?

**Note:** There *are* actually extra pipes after the second `|`, since the `|` character is used as the delimiter for columns.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One solution:

```
:%s!^\([^|]*|\)\{2\}\zs.*!!
```

Explanation:

- [`%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:%25): on every line
- [`s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute): subtitute
- `!`: start of pattern
- [`^`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5E): start of line
- [`\(`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%28): start of group
- [`[^|]*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5B%5D): any number of non-pipe characters
- `|`: followed by a pipe
- `\)`: end of group
- [`\{2\}`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%7B): match two counts of that group
- [`\zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs): start the pattern matching here
- [`.*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C.): any characters
- `!`: end of pattern and start of replacement
- `!`: end of replacement

This will leave lines with fewer than two pipes untouched and will also deal with lines that have more than the two pipes...

**Before**

```
id name things that I don't care no pipes
id|name things that I don't care one pipe
id|name|things that I don't care two pipes
id|name|things that I don't care extra pipe at line end|
id|name|things that I don't care | extra pipe mid-line
id|name|things that I don't| care| two extra pipes
name|things that I don't care missing first column and pipe
|name|things that I don't care missing first column
```

**After**:

```
id name things that I don't care no pipes
id|name things that I don't care one pipe
id|name| 
id|name| 
id|name| 
id|name| 
name|things that I don't care missing first column and pipe
|name|
```

Comment: @Spirit Zhang: Happy to help.

Comment: @JasonDown: Thanks. At school I was taught to show my working; it has stuck with me ever since.

Comment: whoa that was cool, only had to change pipe characters to equal sign and the 2 to a 1.

Answer (score 11):

One can simply repeat the Normal-mode command that jumps to the
character next to the second `|` symbol and deletes the rest of the
text on the line, for each line in the buffer, via the `:normal`
command:

```
:%norm!2f|lD
```

Comment: This is very nice indeed. Far better [VimGolf](http://vimgolf.com/) score than my answer too!

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  Thanks!  I would say it is more natural, since it follows casual editing flow just repeating the commands one uses to perform the task on one line.

Answer (score 1):

If the "don't care" part has no pipes, then

```
:%s/|[^|]*$/|/
```

which also deals with empty "don't care" parts. And it keeps working if you add new fields before the "don't care" part.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
%s/\(.*|.*|\).*/\1
```

Yeap, that worked:

[image: yeap]

Comment: Only if there are exactly two pipes on the line, because "things that I don't care" just might have a pipe... perhaps... you never know. :) #nitpicking

Answer (score 0):

`:%s/[^|]*|[^|]*|\zs.*//`

A variation of what we've already seen.

Match many "not pipe" followed by pipe, twice. Replace with nothing starting from second pipe (\zs).

Comment: This wipes out the second pipe, not just "text after the second '`|`' symbol."

Comment: I know. I tried to be smart. Reading that pipe is the column separator I figured there was no need for one in the end as there is none in the beginning. I should have stated it on the text though.